# I need some Invalid Test Data for Negative Testing

Tags: manual-testing, test-design

I need some valid/invalid test data to test the following:

I am testing a web-based financial application written in .NET technologies. It has a SQL Server back-end. I am testing the UI/Functionality of the application and testing different user profiles, administrator pages, and many financial data reports that are in different formats like PDF, CSV, etc. There are many search parameters for reports based on "Date Range", like data generated Today, yesterday, current month, etc. I can't test all combinations of search parameters combination because it is time consuming.

What are some ways to do Negative scenario testing that can help me find vulnerabilities of the application? I want to test: Input boxes that accept Alpha-numeric characters, test Radio buttons, check-boxes, URL manipulation testing, etc.

Comment: What is your definition of "all kinds"? What page are you trying to test? Different software have different criteria and crash remedies

Answer (score 4):

One of the possible solutions:

- [Generate a random object](http://qala.io/blog/randomized-testing.html) that has all the states different each time
- Use that object to fill the page
- Use that object to check the response. There should be some asserts that understand that "if this is filled, then the response needs to have this"

Running this test multiple times would cover many of the scenarios. But you don't want this to be too generic having only one test that checks everything - the logic would be too complicated. You'd rather still have many smaller tests for particular fields. And by randomizing you won't need to test every possible negative value for each field.

Also, I'm pretty sure that many of these tests can be run as Unit or Component tests which would simplify testing drastically.